# Maven doesn't find my test test classes when building

Tags: java, maven, classpath

I'm running my code from TeamCity and it's having problems compiling by telling me that package does not exist.

I'm thinking that my code is not on the classpath so I need to reconfigure Maven differently. Struggling to find any info on this.

I am pasting my system variables and my POM below:

```
CLASSPATH = .;%JAVA_HOME%\lib;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4
JDK_HOME = %JAVA_HOME%
JRE_HOME = C:\TeamCity\jre
Path = "C:\Projects\BDD\MDA Online Framework\Maven\apache-maven-3.5.4"\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;other path stuff here
M2_HOME = "C:\Projects\BDD\MDA Online Framework\Maven\apache-maven-3.5.4"
MAVEN_HOME = "C:\Projects\BDD\MDA Online Framework\Maven\apache-maven-3.5.4"
```

POM here:

**Edit: I have now added a value to `<testSourceDirectory>` as this was missing. But error still exists.**

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>22.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans-xpath</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6.5.2.jre9-preview</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- specify UTF-8, ISO-8859-1 or any other file encoding -->
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- <testClassesDirectory>s360UIAutomationCC/src/main/java</testClassesDirectory> -->
                    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java/</testSourceDirectory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*MOP_Run_All.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <!-- <excludes> <exclude>**/*RunCukesTest.java</exclude> </excludes> -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    <resources>
    </resources>
    </build>
    <profiles>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

I'm adding the log from TeamCity up to the point where it errors:

```
[11:59:20]Checking for changes
[11:59:21]Publishing internal artifacts
[11:59:21]Clearing temporary directory: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent2nd\temp\buildTmp
[11:59:21]Checkout directory: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent2nd\work\bf68b71269ca1c06
[11:59:21]Updating sources: server side checkout
[11:59:21]Step 1/1: Maven (Maven) (9s)
[11:59:21][Step 1/1] Using watcher: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent2nd\plugins\mavenPlugin\maven-watcher\maven-watcher-agent.jar
[11:59:21][Step 1/1] Initial M2_HOME = C:\Projects\BDD\MDA Online Framework\Maven\apache-maven-3.5.4
[11:59:21][Step 1/1] Current M2_HOME = C:\Projects\BDD\MDA Online Framework\Maven\apache-maven-3.5.4
[11:59:21][Step 1/1] PATH = C:\Projects\BDD\MDA Online Framework\Maven\apache-maven-3.5.4\bin;C:\Projects\BDD\MDA Online Framework\Maven\apache-maven-3.5.4\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Projects\BDD\MDA Online Framework\Maven\apache-maven-3.5.4\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\NTP\bin;C:\Ruby22-x64\bin;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
[11:59:21][Step 1/1] Initial MAVEN_OPTS not set
[11:59:21][Step 1/1] Current MAVEN_OPTS = -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory="C:\Projects\BDD\MDA Online Framework\Maven\apache-maven-3.5.4"
[11:59:21][Step 1/1] Starting: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2\bin\java.exe" "-DDmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\Projects\BDD\MDA Online Framework\Maven\apache-maven-3.5.4" -Dagent.home.dir=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent2nd -Dagent.name=WEBDEVVMWFE2nd -Dagent.ownPort=9094 -Dagent.work.dir=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent2nd\work -Dbuild.number=49 -Dbuild.vcs.number=5045 -Dbuild.vcs.number.1=5045 -Dbuild.vcs.number.SitecoreBdd_TfsHttpMdaRs8080tfsMdaWeb20redevelopmentSitecoreBdd=5045 -Dclassworlds.conf=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent2nd\temp\buildTmp\teamcity.m2.conf -Dcom.jetbrains.maven.watcher.report.file=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent2nd\temp\buildTmp\maven-build-info.xml -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent2nd\temp\buildTmp "-Dmaven.home=C:\Projects\BDD\MDA Online Framework\Maven\apache-maven-3.5.4" -Dmaven.repo.local=C:/Users/SVC_DevBuildAgent/.m2/repository -Dmdafeedkey=Password1 -Dmdafeedurl=http://webdevvmwfe:8085/nuget/MDA+Feeds -Dnugetfeedkey=Password1 -Dnugetfeedurl=http://webdevvmwfe:8085/nuget/mdathirdparty -Dpath.macro.MAVEN.REPOSITORY=c:/.m2/repository -Dteamcity.agent.cpuBenchmark=274 -Dteamcity.agent.dotnet.agent_url=http://localhost:9094/RPC2 -Dteamcity.agent.dotnet.build_id=10695 -Dteamcity.auth.password=geVIwqNiAoewJuElFUtwaPT6i0ve9Iru -Dteamcity.auth.userId=TeamCityBuildId=10695 -Dteamcity.build.changedFiles.file=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent2nd\temp\buildTmp\changedFiles2607574113103246204.txt -Dteamcity.build.checkoutDir=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent2nd\work\bf68b71269ca1c06 -Dteamcity.build.id=10695 -Dteamcity.build.properties.file=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent2nd\temp\buildTmp\teamcity.build8254433068643114691.properties -Dteamcity.build.tempDir=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent2nd\temp\buildTmp -Dteamcity.build.workingDir=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent2nd\work\bf68b71269ca1c06 "-Dteamcity.buildConfName=Build Sitecore BDD" -Dteamcity.buildType.id=SitecoreBdd_Test -Dteamcity.configuration.properties.file=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent2nd\temp\buildTmp\teamcity.config6252402284421596652.properties -Dteamcity.dotnet.nunitaddin=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent2nd\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.TeamCity.NUnitAddin-NUnit -Dteamcity.dotnet.nunitlauncher=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent2nd\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.BuildServer.NUnitLauncher.exe -Dteamcity.dotnet.nunitlauncher.msbuild.task=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent2nd\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.BuildServer.MSBuildLoggers.dll -Dteamcity.dotnet.nunitlauncher1.1=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent2nd\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.BuildServer.NUnitLauncher1.1.exe -Dteamcity.dotnet.nunitlauncher2.0=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent2nd\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.BuildServer.NUnitLauncher2.0.exe -Dteamcity.dotnet.nunitlauncher2.0.vsts=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent2nd\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.BuildServer.NUnitLauncher2.0.VSTS.exe -Dteamcity.dotnet.platform=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent2nd\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.TeamCity.PlatformProcessRunner.1.1.exe -Dteamcity.maven.watcher.home=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent2nd\plugins\mavenPlugin\maven-watcher "-Dteamcity.projectName=Sitecore BDD" -Dteamcity.runner.properties.file=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent2nd\temp\buildTmp\teamcity.runner5425832831152215119.properties -Dteamcity.tests.recentlyFailedTests.file=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent2nd\temp\buildTmp\testsToRunFirst2496520396488952225.txt "-Dteamcity.version=8.0.6 (build 27767)" "-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=\"C:\Projects\BDD\MDA Online Framework\Maven\apache-maven-3.5.4\"" -classpath "C:\Projects\BDD\MDA Online Framework\Maven\apache-maven-3.5.4\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar;" org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher -f "C:\TeamCity\buildAgent2nd\work\bf68b71269ca1c06\MDA Online Framework\pom.xml" -B clean test -DtposUrl=https://tpos-dev.mdanational.com.au/ -DmosURL=https://mos-dev.mdanational.com.au -DmopURL=https://mop-dev.mdanational.com.au/ -DadawaURL=https://adawa-dev.mdanational.com.au/ -DdplURL=https://dpl-dev.mdanational.com.au/ -DoaURL=https://oa-dev.mdanational.com.au/ -DdbPivotalDriver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver -DdbPivotalURL=jdbc:sqlserver://MDAPDCDBS11:1433; -DdbPivotalName=databaseName=MDA-DevelopmentED
[11:59:21][Step 1/1] in directory: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent2nd\work\bf68b71269ca1c06
[11:59:25][Step 1/1] [main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - Scanning for projects...
[11:59:25][Step 1/1] [main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - 
[11:59:25][Step 1/1] [main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - ----------------------< com.mycompany.app:my-app >----------------------
[11:59:25][Step 1/1] [main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - Building my-app 1
[11:59:25][Step 1/1] [main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[11:59:25][Step 1/1] com.mycompany.app:my-app (5s)
[11:59:25][com.mycompany.app:my-app] Importing data from 'C:/TeamCity/buildAgent2nd/work/bf68b71269ca1c06/MDA Online Framework/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml' (not existing file) with 'surefire' processor
[11:59:25][com.mycompany.app:my-app] Surefire report watcher
[11:59:26][com.mycompany.app:my-app] [main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - 
[11:59:26][com.mycompany.app:my-app] [main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ my-app ---
[11:59:26][com.mycompany.app:my-app] [main] INFO org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.CleanMojo - Deleting C:\TeamCity\buildAgent2nd\work\bf68b71269ca1c06\MDA Online Framework\target
[11:59:26][com.mycompany.app:my-app] [main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - 
[11:59:26][com.mycompany.app:my-app] [main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - --- maven-resources-plugin:2.3:resources (default-resources) @ my-app ---
[11:59:26][com.mycompany.app:my-app] [main] INFO org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.DefaultMavenResourcesFiltering - Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[11:59:26][com.mycompany.app:my-app] [main] INFO org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.DefaultMavenResourcesFiltering - Copying 2 resources
[11:59:26][com.mycompany.app:my-app] [main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - 
[11:59:26][com.mycompany.app:my-app] [main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) @ my-app ---
[11:59:27][com.mycompany.app:my-app] [main] INFO org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo - Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[11:59:27][com.mycompany.app:my-app] [main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - 
[11:59:27][com.mycompany.app:my-app] [main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - --- maven-resources-plugin:2.3:testResources (default-testResources) @ my-app ---
[11:59:27][com.mycompany.app:my-app] [main] INFO org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.DefaultMavenResourcesFiltering - Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[11:59:27][com.mycompany.app:my-app] [main] INFO org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.DefaultMavenResourcesFiltering - Copying 8 resources
[11:59:27][com.mycompany.app:my-app] [main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - 
[11:59:27][com.mycompany.app:my-app] [main] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ my-app ---
[11:59:27][com.mycompany.app:my-app] [main] INFO org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.TestCompilerMojo - Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[11:59:27][com.mycompany.app:my-app] [main] INFO org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler - Compiling 27 source files to C:\TeamCity\buildAgent2nd\work\bf68b71269ca1c06\MDA Online Framework\target\test-classes
[11:59:30][com.mycompany.app:my-app] [main] INFO org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.TestCompilerMojo - -------------------------------------------------------------
[11:59:30][com.mycompany.app:my-app] [main] ERROR org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.TestCompilerMojo - COMPILATION ERROR : 
[11:59:30][com.mycompany.app:my-app] [main] INFO org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.TestCompilerMojo - -------------------------------------------------------------
[11:59:30][com.mycompany.app:my-app] [main] ERROR org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.TestCompilerMojo - /C:/TeamCity/buildAgent2nd/work/bf68b71269ca1c06/MDA Online Framework/src/test/java/stepdefs/MOPStepDefs/MOPStepDefs.java:[5,14] package config does not exist
[11:59:30][com.mycompany.app:my-app] [main] ERROR org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.TestCompilerMojo - /C:/TeamCity/buildAgent2nd/work/bf68b71269ca1c06/MDA Online Framework/src/test/java/Database/GetDatabase.java:[3,14] package config does not exist
[11:59:30][com.mycompany.app:my-app] [main] ERROR org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.TestCompilerMojo - /C:/TeamCity/buildAgent2nd/work/bf68b71269ca1c06/MDA Online Framework/src/test/java/stepdefs/TPOSStepDefs/TPOStepDefs.java:[5,14] package config does not exist
[11:59:30][com.mycompany.app:my-app] [main] ERROR org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.TestCompilerMojo - /C:/TeamCity/buildAgent2nd/work/bf68b71269ca1c06/MDA Online Framework/src/test/java/stepdefs/OAStepDefs/OAStepDefs.java:[7,14] package config does not exist
[11:59:30][com.mycompany.app:my-app] [main] ERROR org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.TestCompilerMojo - /C:/TeamCity/buildAgent2nd/work/bf68b71269ca1c06/MDA Online Framework/src/test/java/stepdefs/MOSStepDefs/MOSStepDefs.java:[6,14] package config does not exist
[11:59:30][com.mycompany.app:my-app] [main] ERROR org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.TestCompilerMojo - /C:/TeamCity/buildAgent2nd/work/bf68b71269ca1c06/MDA Online Framework/src/test/java/stepdefs/MOPStepDefs/MOPStepDefs.java:[35,24] cannot find symbol
```

And below is the command that TeamCity is running:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2\bin\java.exe" "-DDmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\Projects\BDD\MDA Online Framework\Maven\apache-maven-3.5.4" -Dagent.home.dir=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent2nd -Dagent.name=WEBDEVVMWFE2nd -Dagent.ownPort=9094 -Dagent.work.dir=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent2nd\work -Dbuild.number=49 -Dbuild.vcs.number=5045 -Dbuild.vcs.number.1=5045 -Dbuild.vcs.number.SitecoreBdd_TfsHttpMdaRs8080tfsMdaWeb20redevelopmentSitecoreBdd=5045 -Dclassworlds.conf=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent2nd\temp\buildTmp\teamcity.m2.conf -Dcom.jetbrains.maven.watcher.report.file=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent2nd\temp\buildTmp\maven-build-info.xml -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent2nd\temp\buildTmp "-Dmaven.home=C:\Projects\BDD\MDA Online Framework\Maven\apache-maven-3.5.4" -Dmaven.repo.local=C:/Users/SVC_DevBuildAgent/.m2/repository -Dmdafeedkey=Password1 -Dmdafeedurl=http://webdevvmwfe:8085/nuget/MDA+Feeds -Dnugetfeedkey=Password1 -Dnugetfeedurl=http://webdevvmwfe:8085/nuget/mdathirdparty -Dpath.macro.MAVEN.REPOSITORY=c:/.m2/repository -Dteamcity.agent.cpuBenchmark=274 -Dteamcity.agent.dotnet.agent_url=http://localhost:9094/RPC2 -Dteamcity.agent.dotnet.build_id=10695 -Dteamcity.auth.password=geVIwqNiAoewJuElFUtwaPT6i0ve9Iru -Dteamcity.auth.userId=TeamCityBuildId=10695 -Dteamcity.build.changedFiles.file=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent2nd\temp\buildTmp\changedFiles2607574113103246204.txt -Dteamcity.build.checkoutDir=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent2nd\work\bf68b71269ca1c06 -Dteamcity.build.id=10695 -Dteamcity.build.properties.file=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent2nd\temp\buildTmp\teamcity.build8254433068643114691.properties -Dteamcity.build.tempDir=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent2nd\temp\buildTmp -Dteamcity.build.workingDir=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent2nd\work\bf68b71269ca1c06 "-Dteamcity.buildConfName=Build Sitecore BDD" -Dteamcity.buildType.id=SitecoreBdd_Test -Dteamcity.configuration.properties.file=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent2nd\temp\buildTmp\teamcity.config6252402284421596652.properties -Dteamcity.dotnet.nunitaddin=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent2nd\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.TeamCity.NUnitAddin-NUnit -Dteamcity.dotnet.nunitlauncher=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent2nd\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.BuildServer.NUnitLauncher.exe -Dteamcity.dotnet.nunitlauncher.msbuild.task=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent2nd\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.BuildServer.MSBuildLoggers.dll -Dteamcity.dotnet.nunitlauncher1.1=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent2nd\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.BuildServer.NUnitLauncher1.1.exe -Dteamcity.dotnet.nunitlauncher2.0=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent2nd\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.BuildServer.NUnitLauncher2.0.exe -Dteamcity.dotnet.nunitlauncher2.0.vsts=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent2nd\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.BuildServer.NUnitLauncher2.0.VSTS.exe -Dteamcity.dotnet.platform=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent2nd\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.TeamCity.PlatformProcessRunner.1.1.exe -Dteamcity.maven.watcher.home=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent2nd\plugins\mavenPlugin\maven-watcher "-Dteamcity.projectName=Sitecore BDD" -Dteamcity.runner.properties.file=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent2nd\temp\buildTmp\teamcity.runner5425832831152215119.properties -Dteamcity.tests.recentlyFailedTests.file=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent2nd\temp\buildTmp\testsToRunFirst2496520396488952225.txt "-Dteamcity.version=8.0.6 (build 27767)" "-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=\"C:\Projects\BDD\MDA Online Framework\Maven\apache-maven-3.5.4\"" -classpath "C:\Projects\BDD\MDA Online Framework\Maven\apache-maven-3.5.4\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar;" org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher -f "C:\TeamCity\buildAgent2nd\work\bf68b71269ca1c06\MDA Online Framework\pom.xml" -B clean test -DtposUrl=https://xxxxxxxx.com.au/ -DmosURL=https://xxxxx.com.au -DmopURL=https://xxxx.com.au/ -DadawaURL=https://xxxx.com.au/ -DdplURL=https://xxxxx.com.au/ -DoaURL=https://xxxxxx.com.au/ -DdbPivotalDriver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver -DdbPivotalURL=jdbc:sqlserver://xxxx:9999; -DdbPivotalName=databaseName=xxx-xxxxopmentED
```

Also adding in project structure:

```
MDA Online Framework
├───.idea
│   ├───dictionaries
│   └───libraries
├───Maven
│   └───apache-maven-3.5.4
│       ├───bin
│       ├───boot
│       ├───conf
│       │   └───logging
│       └───lib
│           ├───ext
│           └───jansi-native
│               ├───freebsd32
│               ├───freebsd64
│               ├───linux32
│               ├───linux64
│               ├───osx
│               ├───windows32
│               └───windows64
├───Reporting
│   ├───ADAWA
│   ├───DPL
│   ├───MOP
│   ├───MOS
│   ├───OA
│   ├───TPOS
│   └───wikipedia.html
├───run
├───Selenium
│   └───libs
├───src
│   ├───main
│   │   ├───java
│   │   └───resources
│   └───test
│       ├───java
│       │   ├───config
│       │   ├───Database
│       │   ├───Pages
│       │   └───stepdefs
│       │       ├───MOPStepDefs
│       │       ├───MOSStepDefs
│       │       ├───OAStepDefs
│       │       └───TPOSStepDefs
│       └───Resources
│           ├───MOP Features
│           ├───MOS Features
│           ├───Online Apps
│           └───TPOS
└───target
    ├───classes
    ├───generated-sources
    │   └───annotations
    ├───generated-test-sources
    │   └───test-annotations
    ├───maven-status
    │   └───maven-compiler-plugin
    │       ├───compile
    │       │   └───default-compile
    │       └───testCompile
    │           └───default-testCompile
    ├───surefire-reports
    └───test-classes
        ├───config
        ├───Database
        ├───MOP Features
        ├───MOS Features
        ├───Online Apps
        ├───Pages
        ├───stepdefs
        │   ├───MOPStepDefs
        │   ├───MOSStepDefs
        │   ├───OAStepDefs
        │   └───TPOSStepDefs
        └───TPOS
```

My class MDABDDConfig is located under package MDA Online Framework\src\test\java\config and the contents of this class are below:

```
package config;

public class MDABDDConfig {

    public static String getTposUrl() {
        return System.getProperty("tposUrl");
    }

    public static String getMosUrl() {
        return System.getProperty("mosURL");
    }
```

My Step def classes (locations mentioned in error log) will call this class such as:

```
//get URL from properties Class
String strMOSurl = MDABDDConfig.getMosUrl();
```

I have since noticed that TeamCity is only picking up classes under my src/test/resources folder and is not picking up anything from my src/test/java folder. This is essentially the cause of this issue but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Set maven environment variables too.

Comment: maven doesn't alter your classpath, it adds libraries to your local repository

Comment: @SumeshTG Sorry, I forgot to mention them in my post. I've edited the post to show these as well.

Comment: What are you doing? What do you expect to happen? What happens instead? Be precise. Post exact and complete commands, code, error messages

Comment: Delete contents of .m2 folder and try again.

Comment: @JBNizet  I am trying to run my build from TeamCity but the build fails due to a "package myPackage does not exist" error. I can run the build fine when running through a command line such as mvn test. But through TeamCity it will fail.

Comment: Be precise. Post exact and complete commands, code, error messages. Note that Maven is a **build** tool. It doesn't **run** your code. It builds it.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks. I wasn't sure about posting the full content given the size of the text. But I realise now it's needed for context. I've added further info to the original post. Hopefully this is clearer now.

Comment: So now we can understand that the problem is when Maven compiles the  tests of your project. It complains about various test classes importing classes from the `config` package. What is the code of the relevant classes. Where are the relevant Java files located?

Comment: @JBNizet The errors reported in the last 6 lines of the TeamCity log are always referring to the point in the various StepDef classes where the line for `import config.MDABDDConfig;` exists. I put a tree up of my project which hopefully shows the location of the classes to you.

Comment: And where is this class config.MDABDDConfig supposed to be? Post the relevant code, tell us precisely where the relevant files are located. We can't see your screen.

Comment: @JBNizet Updated post with more info on the classes at the bottom of post.

Comment: Your code is missing its final curly brace, but I guess this is a copy-paste error. My guess is that you have that class locally, but not on your Teamcity server. Check what you really have on the server. Make sure you're committed/pushed this class to your VCS.

Comment: I just removed class `config.MDABDDConfig` to see if it was just that which was causing the problems but the issue has now moved to the next class. So I think my entire project is not in the Maven build.

Comment: @Matt I think the problem is with your test class names. Maven Surefire Plugin scans for test classes whose names match the following patterns - `**/Test*.java`,
`**/*Test.java`, `**/*Tests.java`, `**/*TestCase.java`. You can however override the default behavior by configuring `include` section which you did. But your pattern `**/*MOP_Run_All.java` doesn't match your test class names.

Comment: Thanks for replying @IndraBasak I'm not sure why but my directory tree above didnt show all files. There is a file located under `\src\Test\java\stepdefs\MOPStepDefs`  called  `MOP_Run_All.java`. This is the test runner. When I run `mvn -test` it will pick up this runner successfully. There are other Classes not arriving in the Maven build though, not just this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the error log you have shared, you are focusing on the wrong problem. It's the compilation of the test classes which is failing and not the execution!

```
[11:59:27][com.mycompany.app:my-app] [main] INFO org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler - Compiling 27 source files to C:\TeamCity\buildAgent2nd\work\bf68b71269ca1c06\MDA Online Framework\target\test-classes
[11:59:30][com.mycompany.app:my-app] [main] INFO org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.TestCompilerMojo - -------------------------------------------------------------
[11:59:30][com.mycompany.app:my-app] [main] ERROR org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.TestCompilerMojo - COMPILATION ERROR :
```

And from the reported path, I can see that it's complaining that package `config` doesn't exist. Your directory layout that the compiler is using is not exactly what you have shown in the directory tree.

```
src/test/java/stepdefs/MOPStepDefs/MOPStepDefs.java:[5,14] package config does not exist
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Feeling a bit silly now as the package 'config' was never checked into source control and therefore not making it into the build. For some reason I had to manually add the new package. Lesson learned!

Answer (score 1):

Maven has a [standard directory layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html). `src/test/java` is only used for test sources. Additionally, maven has a [naming scheme for tests](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#includes).

So your file is in the directory for tests but not named like a test, so I assume maven just ignores it. Would it be possible to move it to `src/test/resources`? That is usually the suitable place for test configurations.